# Can cfdisk be used to resize partitions on a disk that will be accessed by Windows computers?

Tags: dual-boot, cfdisk

**CFDisk** is a fine command-line **partitioning tool** (it seems to change the partition table) for me.

But I have read this on the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cfdisk) that scares me a bit:

> In order to write the partition table cfdisk needs something called
>   the 'geometry' of the disk: the number of 'heads' and the number of
>   'sectors per track'. Linux does not use any geometry, so if the disk
>   will not be accessed by other operating systems, you can safely accept
>   the defaults that cfdisk chooses for you.

Could this be a problem on, say, multi-boot computers that run Linux and **Windows**?

Answer (score 2):

CHS geometry was used in older Windows operating system like Windows 95/98/ME since they are DOS based.

Windows XP and above align at a specific sector and do not check CHS alignment. Those newer Windows will not be affected by that warning.

Beware that moving a newer Windows operating system partition makes them unbootable, partclone.ntfsfixboot will most likely fix the problem by tweaking NTFS alignement values.

Comment: Can we assume the same could be appropriate for any modern operating system, not only Micro$oft Windows?

Comment: With the advent of SSD, one must not align using CHS but using sectors, new operating system align the partition at sector 2048 or sector 8192.  Misalignement slows down the SSD since writing between 2 erase block (those are larger than 512 bytes) will cause an extra read-erase-write cycle to read the miasligned sector before erasing and writing 2 sectors.

Comment: this sounds interesting. Could you please give some practical advice on how to obtain such alignment for SSDing `cfdisk` or `fdisk`?

Comment: ArchLinux's Wiki give much details about how to get it right at this page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning#Partition_alignment

Answer (score 1):

`cfdisk` has been unmaintained for a number of years and is not capable of properly managing modern disk drives.  Use `parted` or `gparted` instead.

Comment: Any proof or arguments? I see [commits](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/commits/master/disk-utils/cfdisk.c) this year, and in 2014/2015.

Comment: Yea, cfdisk and fdisk got a major rewrite during that time frame.  I'm pretty sure it hadn't been released yet when I originally posted this answer, but yea, it is no longer correct.